# How to combine functions to multiple sheet in one script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up a script to enter a different value in cell A1 of each Google Spreadsheet sheet. By entering the csvfeed file in cell A1 I need to grap the current information from the csv sheet into the google spreadsheet.

I have tried using the code below, but it's only updating one sheet, not all of them

```
function storeValue() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName1').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed1.csv")');
}
function storeValue() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName2').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed2.csv")');
}
function storeValue() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName3').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed3.csv")');
}
function storeValue() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName4').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed4.csv")');
}
```

I also tried this:

```
function storeValue() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName1').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed1.csv")');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName2').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed2.csv")');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName3').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed3.csv")');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName4').getRange('A1').setValue('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed4.csv")');
}
```

Script runs, but only one sheet is updated

Comment: The first one won't work at all due to basic principles of how JS works (GAS is JS-based language) - multiple functions under the same name will be disregarded and *only one* will be run (exact order varies, but in a single-file global context it is usually the first one defined). The second should work, unless you define it alongside other `storeValue()` functions. Btw, please, adhere to the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) concept - it will serve you well in the long run (e.g. why call `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` 4 times? Write initial one to variable)

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for you reply. I'm not a developer, so I have actually no clue what I'm doing. I found the code to post to one cell in another topic, but since I'm not familiar with coding, so I was struggling to get it to work on multiple sheets.  I will try the second code another time to see if it does work. 

How would I write the initial call to a variable?

Comment: No worries - but you should at least read through JS [beginner's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps) on MDN - it's easy to get a hang of basics (at least variables, functions, loops and conditionals). As for your question: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`, then reference the variable whenever needed. Note: *if you try the second solution again, delete all other `storeValue()` functions*

Comment: to build on Oleg's suggestion, take a look at the [apps script tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) regarding Sheets, it should give you the basics of how to work with GAS

Comment: I just **changed the sheetNames1,2,3,4 to Sheet1,2,3,4** and tried it with a csv on my website and it **works just fine**.  You probably should use setFormula but I've used setValue() with formulas before I realized there was a setFormula and I've never had any trouble with it.  Perhaps your trying to use sheetName1,2,3,4 as variable sheet names and in that case they shouldn't be quoted but it would be helpful pass them as parameters or show the global declarations.

Comment: It's always helpful if you could provide a [mcve] so that we could verify the problem. This site has spent a great deal of time and effort to show you [ask] better questions. Try taking the [tour] and learn how to help yourself get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function storeValue() {
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

sh.getSheetByName('SheetName1').getRange('A1').setFormula('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed1.csv")');
sh.getSheetByName('SheetName2').getRange('A1').setFormula('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed2.csv")');
sh.getSheetByName('SheetName3').getRange('A1').setFormula('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed3.csv")');
sh.getSheetByName('SheetName4').getRange('A1').setFormula('=importdata("https://example.com/csvfeed4.csv")');
}
```

edit: clarified with one sh call and changed from setvalues to setformulas.

Comment: How this answer the question? What are the relevant changes made to the code posted by the OP?